# How can I prevent the VBA editor from removing internal whitespace?

Tags: vba, excel, editor

I find that aligning identifiers, operators, etc, in my code vastly improves readability. Mistakes just jump off the screen before I ever compile or run the code. However, the VBA editor deletes the extra spaces, destroying my alignment. For example, I try to type a few lines like this:

```
something         = "a" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm A = Something useful
somethingElse     = "b" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm B = Something else
dunno             = "c" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm C = Don't know what this is
whatEver          = "d" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm D = whatever you want
aVar              = "e" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm E = A variable
xOrY              = "f" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm F = Might be X or Y
aLongVariableName = "g" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm G = Long variable name
```

but what I get is this:

```
something = "a" & CStr(iRow1)                      'Colm A = Something useful
somethingElse = "b" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm B = Something else
dunno = "c" & CStr(iRow1)                                  'Colm C = Don't know what this is
whatEver = "d" & CStr(iRow1)                         'Colm D = whatever you want
aVar = "e" & CStr(iRow1)                            'Colm E = A variable
xOrY = "f" & CStr(iRow1)                            'Colm F = Might be X or Y
aLongVariableName = "f" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm G = Long variable name
```

It is much less readable. Not even the comments are aligned. Note how easy it would be to spot a jRow among the iRow's in the first block compared to the second. And did you notice the error in the last row of the non-aligned code ("f" instead of "g")? Not that easy to spot without the alignment.

So how can I prevent the VBA editor from screwing up my alignment by eating the extra spaces?

Comment: Your only option is to right-align your variables and add the whitespace to the beginning of the line

Answer (score 8):

### The VBE (VBA's IDE) has a soul.

And it eats extraneous whitespace for breakfast.

<sub>In other words: you can't do that. Whatever you do, extraneous whitespace will get removed automatically.</sub>

---

### Fine. Now what?

Change your style!

**Naming**

If it's hard to tell `iRow` from `jRow`, then name your row counters for what they are used for: it shouldn't be too hard to tell `playerRow` from `teamRow`.

**Comments**

If every single variable in your code needs a *descriptive* comment, perhaps your variable names aren't *descriptive* enough? Are the comments really useful, or do they merely state the obvious? Do they tell the *what* more than the *why*?

**Declarations**

When a method starts with half a page of local variable declarations, it's a sign that the method might be doing more work than its name says it should be doing; you need to raise the abstraction level and extract functions/procedures. Declaring variables closer to their usage is another way to make code easier to read and to maintain.

**Assignments**

The same rule as *declarations* applies here: the assigned value is used *somewhere else*, perhaps two screens below if you're unlucky.

The point about declaring/assigning closer to usage, is that when you're actually *using* the variable, it's much easier to spot an error if the assigned value is in your face, rather than having to look it up in an "assignment block" somewhere else - even if that block is all aligned & pretty.

```
Dim aLongVariableName As String                'declaration
aLongVariableName = "f" & CStr(iRow1)          'assignment
DoSomethingInvolvingColumnG aLongVariableName  'usage
```

Comment: For all the things about VBA and its editor that encourage bad style, I never thought I'd see something about it that encourages good style. ++

Comment: @mat Sorry Mat, but your answer is completely useless; it doesn't answer my question in any way.

I won't address each of your petty criticisms individually, except to say "WTFO?"

*What if your editor defeated your block intentations?* What if it eliminated extra line feeds?  What if it eliminated ALL whitespace? Effectively that is what the VBA editor is doing: *making my program harder to read without changing its meaning in any way.* There is no value added by eating up my extra spaces. Horizontal space is CHEAP!!! It's the vertical space that is precious.

Comment: @RubberDuck: I don't think I understand your point. How does preventing readability = good style? Or are you agreeing with me that this is a real problem that should be fixed?

Comment: @riderBill it prevents one kind of readability, but promotes the kind of readability MatsMug was talking about. I completely agree that if you think you need a comment for every variable, what you really need is better names and smaller routines. I also wouldn't hold your breath waiting on Microsoft to "fix" this. 1) It's likely they purposely added this as a feature and is by design. 2) To the best of my knowledge there are only a handful of people working on improving the VBE, and none of them work for Microsoft. I encourage you to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You guys are missing the point. The question was _how to make the editor let me line up my code._ I didn't ask about the use of comments or assignment statements (and BTW @mat, they are *assignments*, not *declarations*. Learn the terminology). My example code is for illustration.

Comment: As far as my coding style, column alignment can aid readability for _any_ code construct. It illuminates typos, omissions, and (some) other errors. It is a godsend when revisiting old code (or someone else's code). Also, column alignment really brings out the power of column mode editors (which as far as I know is another VBE deficiency).

Comment: Well the answer is "[**You can't**, not without making your code look very very odd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28956251/1188513)". Get over it.

Comment: Don't take our words for it. [I've made this point before](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/73426/41243).

Comment: @Mat Sorry for the snide comment. SO won't let me edit it out of the comment. I was just a little wound up. I really hate VBA. I'm only using it to help out a friend.

Answer (score 4):

```
        something = "a" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm A = Something useful
    somethingElse = "b" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm B = Something else
            dunno = "c" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm C = Don't know what this is
         whatEver = "d" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm D = whatever you want
             aVar = "e" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm E = A variable
             xOrY = "f" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm F = Might be X or Y
aLongVariableName = "g" & CStr(iRow1)  'Colm G = Long variable name
```

Comment: Yes, that is an improvement. But my example code was a simple case. Over the years (in other programming languages) I have found that wasting a lot of horizontal white space saves a lot of programming time and avoids errors and frustration. I'll try your right justified method next time, but for more complicated expressions I suspect I will still be frustrated. I cannot see why Microsoft's editor would worry about a few extra meaningless bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the continuation character '_' to 'fudge' it as follows:

```
something = _
                    "a" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm A = Something useful
somethingElse = _
                    "b" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm B = Something else
dunno = _
                    "c" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm C = Don't know what This is
whatEver = _
                    "d" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm D = whatever you want
aVar = "e" _
                        & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm E = A variable
xOrY = _
                    "f" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm F = Might be X or Y
aLongVariableName = _
                    "f" & CStr(iRow1)          'Colm G = Long variable name
```

Comment: I've actually done that on occasion, esp. on long function declarations with lots of parameters (I like long variable names, and with all the _byRef_, _byVal_, and _as type_ descriptors, one more line of vertical space is worth it for the readability. But in general, vertical space is worth 10x what horizontal space is worth. That's especially true with my (in other languages) very readable style. Strange that the VBA editor is inconsistent about white space on continuation lines. It really is a goofy language.

Comment: BTW, why hasn't the first "answer" above been removed? It doesn't even attempt to answer the question. It's just a rambling criticism of the junk code that I used to illustrate my question. And even the criticism is pointless. Some of you high point guys flag it as "not an answer" for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm Fudge

I replaced these 2...

```
Public Function inc(ByRef int_ThisInteger As Long, Optional boo_UpdateSource As Boolean = True) As Long

     inc = int_ThisInteger + 1
     
     If boo_UpdateSource Then int_ThisInteger = int_ThisInteger + 1

End Function

Public Function Dec(ByRef int_ThisInteger As Long, Optional boo_UpdateSource As Boolean = True) As Long

     Dec = int_ThisInteger - 1
     
     If boo_UpdateSource Then int_ThisInteger = int_ThisInteger - 1

End Function
```

with...

```
Public Function bao(ByRef ThisNumber As Variant _
                  , Optional ByVal ArithmaticOperator As enu_BasicArithmaticOperators = 0 _
                  , Optional ByVal HowMany As Variant = 1 _
                  , Optional ByVal WholeNumbersOnly As Boolean = True _
                  , Optional ByVal UpdateSource As Boolean = True) As Variant
                    
     On Error GoTo CatchAllErrorTrap
     
          Dim StartingValue As Double: StartingValue = Val(ThisNumber)
          Dim ThisMany As Double: ThisMany = Val(HowMany)
          
          Select Case ArithmaticOperator
               Case Is = bao_Addition       : bao = StartingValue + ThisMany
               Case Is = bao_Subtraction    : bao = StartingValue - ThisMany
               Case Is = bao_Multiplication : bao = StartingValue * ThisMany
               Case Is = bao_Division       : bao = StartingValue / ThisMany
               Case Is = bao_Perccentage    : bao = ThisMany * StartingValue /     100
               Case Is = bao_Power          : If ThisMany >= 0 Then bao =     StartingValue ^ ThisMany Else Stop: End
               Case Is = bao_Root           : If ThisMany >= 0 Then bao = StartingValue ^ (1 / ThisMany) Else Stop: End
               Case Else: Stop: End: ' undefined arithmetic operator
          End Select
          
          If WholeNumbersOnly Then bao = Round(bao, 0)
          bao = Trim(Str(bao))
          If UpdateSource Then ThisNumber = Val(bao)
          
          GoTo CommonExit

CommonExit:
     On Error GoTo 0
     Exit Function

CatchAllErrorTrap:
     Stop: ' take a moment to understand my mistake. chances are it is a type     conversion error
     bao = "Error"
     If UpdateSource Then ThisNumber = bao
     Resume CommonExit

End Function
```

But only at the expense of...

```
Public Enum enu_BasicArithmaticOperators

     bao_Addition        = 0
     bao_Subtraction     = 1
     bao_Multiplication  = 2
     bao_Division        = 3
     bao_Perccentage     = 4
     bao_Power           = 5
     bao_Root            = 6

End Enum
```

using the Block character asc(255)

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("2^27")
```

becomes

```
debug.Print bao(2, bao_Power          , 27)
```

But I like it. All a matter of taste. Now where did I put that fudge.

I agree with a previous contributor that sensible names negate the need to comment  everything.

Ian.